# xpages send mail to a specific address

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I try to create a button which send a mail using the doc's URL to a mail-adress entered in an editBox:

```
 if(Contr.isNewNote()){
    Contr.save();
}
var thisdoc = Contr.getDocument(true);
var tempdoc = database.createDocument();
tempdoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
tempdoc.replaceItemValue("SendTo", thisdoc.getItemValue("Destinatari"));
tempdoc.replaceItemValue("Subject", "My application");
var tempbody:NotesRichtextItem = tempdoc.createRichTextItem("Body");
tempbody.appendText("Click for open the doc. in client")
tempbody.addNewLine(2);
tempbody.appendDocLink(thisdoc);
tempbody.addNewLine(2);
thisdoc.save(true,true);
tempbody.appendText("click for navigating via web")
tempbody.addNewLine(2);
tempbody.appendText(facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getRequestURL().toString() + 
          "?action=readDocument&documentId=" + thisdoc.getUniversalID());
tempdoc.send();
thisdoc.recycle();
tempbody.recycle();
tempdoc.recycle();
```

But at `tempdoc.send();` I get Exception occurred calling method NotesDocument.send() null

What is weird, is the fact that for an application on the same server the code is working, I just copy the code and just modified the doc `datasource` and the `SendTo` field name. Am I missing something? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just a thought, can you debug the sendTo value before sending...

Comment: Also, check the XPages log file for more details on the send error

Comment: Minor inefficiency to note: thisdoc.save is not necessary and may actually cause rep/saves if you leave it in there. You have already saved thisdoc when you did Contr.save in line#2.

Answer (score 0):

I forget the issue but there's been reports of this problem I think if a bad character gets into the sendTo.

There's a comment on the email bean XSnippet:  http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=emailbean-send-dominodocument-html-emails-cw-embedded-images-attachments-custom-headerfooter

that said:
The solution that seems to work is to use the method :

```
emailHeader.addValText(xxx,"UTF-8")
```

instead of

```
emailHeader.setHeaderVal(xxx)
```

I'm not exactly sure how that might translate to SSJS..  but the problem might be with special characters..